# Dialogflow sending image back to webhook fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, fulfillment

Am able to send image or Card back on /webhook route because sender is included in request object.  But sender is not included in /ai (fulfillment webhook url).

```
request({
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
qs: {access_token:token},
method: 'POST',
json: {
    recipient: {id:sender},
    message: messageData,
}
```

But, my fulfillment route is /ai and the REQ body does not include the sender, so I always get this error where trying to send back anything but just text.

```
Error:  { message:
```

'(#100) Message cannot be empty, must provide valid attachment or text',
  type: 'OAuthException’,

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're using [the NodeJS client library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) with Actions on Google, after you identify a user's intent, you can send an image in the following manner:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/imgs/160204193356-01-cat-500.jpg',
    alt: 'A cat',
  }))
})
```

For more info on getting started with Actions on Google, check out Google's codelabs,

1. [Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 1)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0)
2. [Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 2)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#0)